# What is wrong with size classes?

Tags: ios, size-classes

I have created a new project. And set a UILabel into two position depending on size classes, but `wCompact, hAny` can not trigger in iPhone simulator. I have set label x position to 0, but it is still on 15px as on `wAny, hAny`. Why? Use Size Classes is set. I am using Xcode beta 3.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Who the hell know what Apple did with Size classes :/ sorry m8!

Comment: So not I am the only one who is struggling with size classes under beta Xcode?

Comment: I think that u r the only one that struggle with this, others just avoid that :), same as auto layout.. Just kidding man!

Comment: Did you add a constrained to keep it at 0 px from the left?

Comment: I forget set constrains, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forget to set constrains. Set size-classes have nothing to do with view's position, to position views needs only to set up constrains.

Comment: That's nothing to do with size classes. That's the same for AutoLayout for the past 2 years :) (I didn't down vote BTW)

Comment: I could set different positions by selecting different size classes, and I thought positions will be dependent also from orientations, but now I know not, only if constrains are used too

Answer (score 0):

You have missed to set the margin. I faced this issue in `Xcode 6`. Select constraints to margin. If you are designing for backward compatibility (that is for lower versions of `iOS`) the don't select constraints to margin. Just set the constraints manually by giving position values.